# mdoc(7) markup for accumulating options with arguments

Tags: manpage, troff

is there a "proper" or "canonical" markup for a command (section 1) "accumulating" option with argument?  (or without for that matter)

an accumulating option can be given multiple times and the effects add up: think gcc's `-I` or `-W`.

let's say i'm documenting *ssh(1)*.  i want the `SYNOPSIS` to give away that `-v` and `-o` accumulate, this is usually done with ellipses:

```
ssh [-o option]... [-v]...
```

i'd like to tack the ellipsis to the idiomatic

```
.Op Fl o Ar option
```

the closest i can get is

```
.Oo
. Fl o Ar option
.Oc Ns \&...
```

as the shorthand `Op` coopts it.

what do other people do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a novice at man pages, but aside from your workaround, the closest I can get is:

`.Op [ Fl o Ar option ] No ...`

However, this results in:

`[[-o option ] ...]`

It's not exactly canonical or precisely what you're hoping for, but it seems unambiguous. (See http://docopt.org for other examples of how this can be expressed.)